# z-index not working with absolute block on relative block

Tags: css, z-index

I'm trying to bring up a sub menu to the front by clicking on an element. The sub menu (blue) is supposed to overlay the navigation menu (yellow) below, but it does not.

Here's a demo with the broken behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/rqeRC/1/

```
sub menu == #profileMenu
navigation menu == #navigation
```

The sub menu is an absolute positioned block with z-index 3 while the navigation menu is a relative positioned block with z-index 2. Doesn't seem to work this way.

Note: I do need the z-index to keep these elements in the foreground due to already having fixed elements in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the z-index on `#profile` higher than on `#navigation`. E.g.

```
#profile {
    float: right;
    margin: 60px 47px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: Aww I didn't realize #profileMenu was within #profile. So the parent's z-index is used for rendering in combination with relative/absolute.

Answer (score 0):

## navigation and #profileMenu has the same z-index, which is 2, set profileMenu's z-index to a higher value.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rqeRC/2/

```
#profile {
    float: right;
    margin: 60px 47px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
#navigation {
    float: right;
    margin: 60px 47px 0px 0px;
    min-height: 248px;
    position: relative;
    width: 248px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: You mixed up #profileMenu and #profile, but yea, I did as well. ^^